# delete key and value in a dict if a string is matched in either key or value

Tags: python-3.x

I will get a dictionary which contains sub dictionaries and key : val pairs.

for Example :

> dict = {"1" : "one", "2" : "two", "3" : {"one" : "1", "two" : "2"}}

this dictionary is not fixed i will get it randomly and it is contains multiple key : val pairs and some sub dicts.

My requirement is to loop through all keys, values and delete the key, val pair if i found a string in it in that particular sub dict.

Comment: which one do you want to match with the key or the value of the dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def delete_key(dict_obj):

    for key, val in dict_obj.items():

        if type(val) == 'dict':
            delete_key(val)

        if type(val) == 'str':
            print(key + ' - > ' + val)
            # Below line will delete you key
            del dict_obj[val]
            # DO YOUR VERIFICATION LOGIC HERE 
            # AND DELETE KEY
```

Use above method to remove key. Fine tune this method as per your requirement.

Comment: but i am unable to delete the key while iterating through dictionary...  how can i delete a dict in 3rd fourth or nth intteration?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {"1": {"a": "a"}, "2": "a", "3": {"p": "pi", "t": "ti"}}
print(a)
for el in a:
    if type(a[el]) is dict:
        for inner_el in a[el]:
            print(a[el])
            if a[el][inner_el] == "ti":
                del(a[el][inner_el])
                break
print(a)
```

output

```
{'1': {'a': 'a'}, '2': 'a', '3': {'p': 'pi', 't': 'ti'}}
{'a': 'a'}
{'p': 'pi', 't': 'ti'}
{'p': 'pi', 't': 'ti'}
{'1': {'a': 'a'}, '2': 'a', '3': {'p': 'pi'}}
```

this works only if there is one key to delete